# Facebook Like plugin - Canonical URL in response is pointing to some random domain

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

When I enter my page URL http://korydor.in.ua/reviews/1507-vzyat-na-karandash to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ I can see that Canonical URL is pointing to some random ya.ru domain.

[image]

How to get in touch with Facebook dev team to fix that ?

This page has relevant metadata information, it is not a case of the problem

*meta property="og:url" content="http://korydor.in.ua/reviews/1507-vzyat-na-karandash"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further down that same page it explains why this is happening, screenshot attached

[image: screenshot]

Your site is redirecting Facebook's crawler - you need to stop redirecting the crawler if you want the metadata for that URL instead of the after-redirect URL

Comment: Thanks for noticing those redirects - they were caused by the malicious script work altering .htaccess redirect rules at my domain.

Shall patch the security hole at my setup....